# React Recharts -> Tooltip problem with LabelList in Scatter chart

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, scatter-plot, recharts

We are facing for some time problem with LabelList which is displayed over the elements of Scatter chart. If user is hovering over them, Tooltip is not displayed.

Code:

```
const {ScatterChart, Scatter, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, LabelList, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;
const data = [{x: 100, y: 200, z: 200}, {x: 120, y: 100, z: 260},
                  {x: 170, y: 300, z: 400}, {x: 140, y: 250, z: 280},
                  {x: 150, y: 400, z: 500}, {x: 110, y: 280, z: 200}]

const SimpleScatterChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <ScatterChart width={400} height={400} margin={{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20}}>
        <XAxis type="number" dataKey={'x'} name='stature' unit='cm'/>
        <YAxis type="number" dataKey={'y'} name='weight' unit='kg'/>
        <CartesianGrid />
        <Tooltip cursor={{strokeDasharray: '3 3'}}/>
        <Legend onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} />
        <Scatter name='A school' data={data} fill='#8884d8'>
          <LabelList dataKey="x" />
        </Scatter>
      </ScatterChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleScatterChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/gvsspn0h/

Once you will remove LabelList, it is working fine:

```
const {ScatterChart, Scatter, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, LabelList, Tooltip, Legend} = Recharts;
const data = [{x: 100, y: 200, z: 200}, {x: 120, y: 100, z: 260},
                  {x: 170, y: 300, z: 400}, {x: 140, y: 250, z: 280},
                  {x: 150, y: 400, z: 500}, {x: 110, y: 280, z: 200}]

const SimpleScatterChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <ScatterChart width={400} height={400} margin={{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20}}>
        <XAxis type="number" dataKey={'x'} name='stature' unit='cm'/>
        <YAxis type="number" dataKey={'y'} name='weight' unit='kg'/>
        <CartesianGrid />
        <Tooltip cursor={{strokeDasharray: '3 3'}}/>
        <Legend onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave} />
        <Scatter name='A school' data={data} fill='#8884d8'>
        </Scatter>
      </ScatterChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleScatterChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gt0uy92a/2/

Problem is, we need LabelList displayed as it is in a first example, we can't change the position, but Tooltip must be working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LabelList 
  dataKey="x" 
  style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}}
/>
```

will work for you.you can bind **onMouseEnter** event to **LabelList** component as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was not so simple, it was little bit tricky, but still logical. If we can't do anything with way how is SVG rendering elements, can't use z-index, we still can set them opacity.

```
const CustomizedCircle = props => {
    const {
        cx, cy, fill, size, z,
    } = props;
    const radius = size / 70;
    const value = z;

    return (
        <svg width={radius} height={radius} style={{overflow: 'visible'}}>
            <text style={{fontWeight: FONT_WEIGHT, fontSize: FONT_SIZE}} x={cx} y={cy + 5} textAnchor="middle">{value}</text>
            <circle style={{opacity: OPACITY}} cx={cx} cy={cy} r={radius} fill={fill} />
        </svg>
    );
};
```

So we are first rendering the text, then we render the circle and to see text beneath the circle we are setting the circle some kind of opacity.